# Is it possible to add Service Console to a community?

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-community

Is it possible to add Service Console to the Lightning Community that i have built. We can create Case object detail page as New Object Page option. But i wanted to add service console because its easy to use. It has a split view table which displays all the recently viewed cases (collapsible pane). This would be a lot better user experience than using normal Case object page.

[image]

Note: Without adding the App Launcher would be nice

Any body has any idea how can i achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Community licenses are the cheapest 10-25$ per user per month, Service console licenses cost start at 150$, if Salesforce allows a way to use rich Service console on cheap licences why would anyone buy expensive service cloud platform licenses.

So to answer, No you cannot directly use the service console in the community.

That being said, if you have an abundance of developers you can try implementing similar functionality using lightning components.